# Помощь в переводе кода с С++ на С#

Tags: c#, c++

Возникла проблема в том, что нужно создать программу с интерфейсом пользователя, так как мне удобнее сделать это в Windows Forms, нужен перевести код с С++ на С#
Вот код, кому не сложно, помогите, ибо у самого не выходит

```
int main (){

char str[255];
int chars[256] = { 0 }; 
cin >> str;

for (int j = 0; j <= 255; j++)
  if (str[j] > 0)
    str[j] = toupper (str[j]); 

for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) 
  chars[str[i]]++;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  if (chars[i])
    cout << char (i) << " repeated " << chars[i] << " times\n";
```

}

Comment: программа должна выводить символ, и то, какое кол-во раз он повторяется в строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализируем строку сразу вводом из консоли:

```
string str = Console.Readline ();
```

Если используются формы, то нужно будет взять текст из поля ввода.

В шарпе тип `char` двухбайтовый, поэтому если решать через массив, то размер должен быть 65536. Нулями он уже будет заполнен при создании. Есть еще такие штуки как `Dictionary` и `SortedDictionary`, если захочется не выделять столько памяти, можно будет использовать их.

```
var chars = new int [65536];
```

Перебираем строку:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
    char c = str [i];
```

А можно и так:

```
foreach (char c in string) {
```

Увеличиваем нужный счетчик

```
    chars [(int) c]++;
}
```

Ну и вывод:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
```

Здесь есть один момент: в шарпе нет неявного преобразования `int` в `bool`.

```
    if (chars [i] > 0) {
        Console.WriteLine ("символ " + (char) i + " встретился " + chars [i] + " раз");
    }
}
```

В примере опять же вывод в консоль используется, но я думаю, с компонентами проблем возникнуть не должно (там обычно свойство `Text` за текст отвечает), если возникнут, напишите в комментарии какие компоненты используете, я тогда отредактирую ответ.

Comment: все окей, разберусь с компонентами, а что на счет перевода каждого символа в верхний или нижний регистр? (например "А" и "а", должны восприниматься как одинаковые символы)

Comment: Метод `Char.ToLower ('A')` вернет `'a'`, `Char.ToUpper ('a')` вернет `'A'`. У строки есть тоже такой метод: `str2 = str1.ToLower()` запишет в `str2` строку `str1` всю в нижнем регистре.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.char.tolower?view=netframework-4.7.2